# about extruding vertex

Tags: modeling

I saw this blender timelapse video on youtube and during the course,he was translating a vertex in z axis but vertexes around it randomly gravitates towards that particular vertex as well,I'm new into the blender,I've only saw similar feature in cinema4d but I couldn't find any clue on my own,if somebody knows how to achieve it please let me know,thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWBzu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think he's not extruding, just moving up, no? He must have activated the *Proportional Editing* option, and perhaps *Random* type?

[image]

Comment: oh yes,it worked,I was trying it before but forgot to scale up the proportional size factor,thank you very much!